# Rhapsody Developer for C 8.2.1

Tags: c++, package, rhapsody

I'm trying to add a new package in a rhapsody developer c++ projects, and after I right click on the project -> add new package - > enter the name of the package , the package folder appears un bold like the others.
How can I make my recently created package to appear bold like the others?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to add that package to the SCOPE of the component that also contains the surrounding items.  Rhapsody's UI will bold or un-bold artifacts in the navigation window depending on whether or not they are in the scope list of the currently selected and active component.  You can ensure that future adds (new packages) automatically get added to component scope by changing the level at which you select which artifacts get added to component scope.  Just open the component, goto the "scope" tab and find the set of packages and go UP one level to the containing package for those packages and select that such that it automatically selects all of the contained packages.  Hope this was clear.